# How can I access, edit, delete and update the outlook To-Do list by outlook Add-in without using the Graph API

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin

currently, I have to build an add-in that can perform the CRUD operation in the Outlook to-do list using office js api, is it even possible to access the Outlook to-do list without Graph API?